# Can't upload image to S3 bucket using direct url of image

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Here is my code, which works for forms upload (via $_FILES) (I'm omitting that part of the code because it is irrelevant):

```
$file = "http://i.imgur.com/QLQjDpT.jpg";

$s3 = S3Client::factory(array(
    'region' => $region,
    'version' => $version
));  

        try {

            $content_type = "image/" . $ext;

            $to_send = array();

            $to_send["SourceFile"] = $file;

            $to_send["Bucket"] = $bucket;
            $to_send["Key"] = $file_path;
            $to_send["ACL"] = 'public-read';
            $to_send["ContentType"] = $content_type;

            // Upload a file.
            $result = $s3->putObject($to_send);
```

As I said, this works if file is a `$_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"]` but fails if $file is a valid image url with Uncaught exception 'Aws\Exception\CouldNotCreateChecksumException' with message `'A sha256 checksum could not be calculated for the provided upload body, because it was not seekable. To prevent this error you can either 1) include the ContentMD5 or ContentSHA256 parameters with your request, 2) use a seekable stream for the body, or 3) wrap the non-seekable stream in a GuzzleHttp\Psr7\CachingStream object. You should be careful though and remember that the CachingStream utilizes PHP temp streams. This means that the stream will be temporarily stored on the local disk.'`. Does anyone know why this happens? What might be off? Tyvm for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to download the file to the server where PHP is running first. S3 uploads are only for local files - which is why `$_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"]` works - its a file that's local to the PHP server.

Comment: You're populating `$to_send["SourceFile"]` with a string. You want something like `file_put_contents(file_get_contents($url),'/tmp/tmpfile'); $to_send["SourceFile"] = '/tmp/tmpfile';` - basically download the file first then send that file.

Comment: how about the option #3, the CachingStream? I would like to use that but it seems i can't get it work.

Answer (score 4):

For anyone looking for option #3 (CachingStream), you can pass the `PutObject` command a `Body` stream instead of a source file.

```
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream;
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\CachingStream;
...
$s3->putObject([
    'Bucket'        => $bucket,
    'Key'           => $file_path,
    'Body'          => new CachingStream(
        new Stream(fopen($file, 'r'))
    ),
    'ACL'           => 'public-read',
    'ContentType'   => $content_type,
]);
```

Alternatively, you can just request the file using guzzle.

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
$response = $client->get($file);

$s3->putObject([
    'Bucket'        => $bucket,
    'Key'           => $file_path,
    'Body'          => $response->getBody(),
    'ACL'           => 'public-read',
    'ContentType'   => $content_type,
]);
```

Comment: Thanks so much Kyro - that worked great (the top one)! Anyone reading htis - make darn sure you set your $content_type correctly. I was uploading a test PDF using image/jpg (more test code) and it wasn't working... application/pdf worked great!