# AWS uploading image results in uploading empty file

Tags: php, image, amazon-web-services, file-upload

I am trying to upload image after processing it with PHP to AWS. When I try to upload image that is already in the folder on my server the image uploads with no issue. However adding the same script into script that process uploaded image (which works saving images locally, creating cropped version and uploading link to them to local db), resize it and after reading exif data rotates correctly I only upload empty file (correctly named) that does not look like na image (downloading it from AWS I get error message that the image is broken) and after inspecting it it usually has only around 76b. What gives? Does that mean that the script needs some time to process the resizing / rotating information and therefore it uploads image that is half ready? I do not get any error messages or warnings back.

My script for the local file upload:

```
try{
    $result = $s3->putObject([
        'Bucket'     => $config['s3']['bucket'],
        'Key'        => 'uploads/test.jpg',
        'Body' => WWW_ROOT.'/penguin/xcropped/test.jpg',
        'ACL' => 'public-read',
    ]);
} catch (S3Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage() . "\n";
}


$image_path =  $result['ObjectURL'];
```

My script in the resizing and cropping script:

```
      require_once('inc/aws_connect.inc.php');

    try{
        $result = $s3->putObject([
            'Bucket'     => $config['s3']['bucket'],
            'Key'        => 'uploads/test2.jpg',
            'Body' => WWW_ROOT.$thumb_path,
            'ACL' => 'public-read',
        ]);
    } catch (S3Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage() . "\n";
    }


    $aws_result = $result['ObjectURL'];


echo $aws_result;
```

Does anyone knows why is this happening and what might be the issue. The images are around 1.7MB size. Is this maybe a problem?

Comment: what kind of ```mime-type``` is recognized by S3? Maybe after crop you lose this information

Comment: It does recognise image/jpg, and I did test where I specifically passed that over, I think it might have something to do with the fact that it can upload the file straight from $_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"], but can not easily from server as mentioned over here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34251296/cant-upload-image-to-s3-bucket-using-direct-url-of-image

Comment: Double-check the contents of the file that you're uploading are correct. Also, download the resulting file from S3 and open it with a text editor or binary editor. If it's only 76 bytes, as you claim, then what are those bytes? Do they give you any clue as to what your code is doing incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

In order for it to correctly work you need to have Guzzle and stream the file over to AWS. This worked for me:

```
  use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream;
  use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\CachingStream;

  try{
    $aws_result = $s3->putObject([

  'Bucket'        => $config['s3']['bucket'],
  'Key'           => 'thumbs/thumb_' . $random_string,
  'Body'          => new CachingStream(
      new Stream(fopen(WWW_ROOT.$thumb_path, 'r'))
  ),
  'ACL'           => 'public-read',
  'ContentType'   => 'image/jpg',


  ]);
} catch (S3Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage() . "\n";
}


    $aws_result = $aws_result['ObjectURL'];
```